# Pegar retorno de uma função PHP em JS

Tags: php, javascript

estou iniciando agora e  minha dúvida é simples,  eu tenho uma função  criada dentro de uma class em um arquivo php, e quero pegar o retorno dessa função em outro arquivo javascript, como faço isso?  tem algo a vê com requisição ajax?.

**Arquivo Php, a função é algo assim**

```
public function minhaFunção()
{
[..]
        if($data!=0)
        {
            $prerollModel->prerollCount();

            $TemId = true;      
        }
        else
        {
            $TemId = false;     
        }

        return $TemId;
}
```

**Arquivo js**

```
var retorno = o retorno da função;
```

Comment: Está a usar jquery?

Comment: Sim, estou usando jquery.

Comment: Utilize [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) conforme a resposta do @Miguel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para isso pode fazer um get por um [ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) simples com jquery:

```
$.get("arquivo.php", function(data) {
  alert("Retorno: " +data);
});
```

Para isto onde pus o `"arquivo.php"` coloque o caminho para o seu script php e troque o `return $TemId;` deste por:

```
echo $TemId;
```

Caso queira manter o `return $TempId` então rastreie se o pedido veio por ajax, se vier faça echo em vez de `return`:

```
if (strtolower(filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH')) === 'xmlhttprequest') {
   echo $TemId; // é ajax
}
else {
   return $TempId;
}
```

Exemplo funcional:

```js
$.get("https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/topstories.json?print=pretty", function(data) {
  alert( "Retorno: " +data[0]); // [0] é só para este exemplo no seu não precisa do [0]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```